# Surjections and injections of compositions

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Is someone willing to help me a bit with this one? I know that this solution is not correct.

Let $A,B,C$ be sets. Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$ be functions. Assume that $h = g \circ f$ is surjective and that $g$ is injective. Show that $f$ is surjective.

My solution:

Since $h$ is surjective, for all y there exist a $x$ so that $g(f(x))=y$. Since $g$ is injective, for all $z,z'$ we know that $g(z)=g(z') \implies z=z'$.

Hence there exist $x$ for all $z$ such that $f(x)=z$?

Comment: Start with $b \in B$ and look at $g(b)\in C$.  Use surjectivity of $g\circ f$.

Comment: Let $b \in B$. Since $g$ is injective this must be $f$. Since $h$ is surjective, there exist $x$ so that $f(x)=b$?

Comment: Start your proof with what you need to show: surjectivity of $f$. So, we take $b\in B$ and must find $a\in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. Apply surjectivity of $gf$ to a certain element of $C$ and then injectivity of $g$ to conclude what you need.

Comment: I guess this should be relatively uncomplicated...